# Spinner shows the name of first item on list

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, spinner

Hello i am new to android. I have created a spinner. There are some items on spinner and the problem is the name of the first item is automatically shown along with the icon of spinner at start. How can i make spinner such that only icon is visible initially?

Following is my array

```
<string-array name="settingSpinner">
    <item>change pw</item>
    <item>Log Out</item>

</string-array>
```

In the main class

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources()
            .getStringArray(R.array.settingSpinner));
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    settings.setAdapter(adapter);

    settings.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                   int position, long id) {
            Object item = arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(item),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question more and post your code what you have done

Comment: Spinner shows the first element by default

Comment: @FaizMir i have posted my code. please take a look at it :) thank you

Comment: @AIK is there any way to remove that first element at start?

Comment: @Sudeep you can set a mode for spinner set it to dialog mode

Comment: by default the spinner will show the first element

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786822/hide-first-item-in-the-spinner

Comment: you can use `spinner.setPrompt("header");`

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit it will only work in dialog mode

Comment: @FaizMir as long as it works no issue :D it's just suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1

You can add place holder text at first index of array.

```
<string-array name="settingSpinner">
    <item>Choose Action</item> // add this placeholder
    <item>change pw</item>
    <item>Log Out</item>    
</string-array>
```

Check when selected if index is not 0.

```
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                               int position, long id) {
    if(position != 0) // proceed further
    }
```

#### Solution 2

Add black string on first position

```
<string-array name="settingSpinner">
    <item> </item>
    <item>change pw</item>
    <item>Log Out</item>    
</string-array>
```

This will show up black space on Spinner on activity start.

Comment: I did try the second solution. In the first solution the place holder will be seen right? is there any way so thay i can only show the dropdown icon but not any place holder?

Comment: Then use second solution.